# Transfer website with all categories, articles, menus

Tags: joomla-3.6, migration

I have started developing a website on Joomla! 3.6.5 and need to know if I can later transfer the whole webpage with all the content to a web server without loosing the information (categories, articles and menus).

Is there an export function or something of this kind or if I just copy and paste the installation over FTP to the server it will be OK?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you're just migrating from one server to the next (e.g. development to production).

Look at Akeeba Backup.  It is capable of transferring an entire site from one physical/virtual system to another, including the database.

https://www.akeebabackup.com/

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Articles and category,

Yes, You can also do the same using taking backup of few tables.
You have to taken a backup of Content,Assets and category tables.

About Menu you can do the same but here you have to see all the things properly. Here it would be easy for you to add those only Menu from export file as you need.

Comment: What I think the OP meant to ask in a simpler words, is how to transfer the whole Joomla website from one location to another - and he didn't want to distinguish the articles, categories etc, or simply move this sub-part of data somewhere. So actually your answer isn't going to help him achieve what he wants. Likely he isn't really understand what you are trying to say here and what the outcome will be with your answer. But anyhow since in his question title articles and categories are mentioned, your post tries to cover this.